# BindingRedirect not being honored within cloud service

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services

I'm receiving an exception when initializing a cloud service:

`System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35`

Understanding that I have version `4.3.0.0` installed, I have added the following redirect into the `app.config` for my worker:

```
<dependentAssembly>
  <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.3.0.0" newVersion="4.3.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

When run locally within the local emulator this resolves the issue. When this is packaged through `cspack` the `app.config` and `worker.dll.config` are included in the `package.xml`, both have the binding redirect included.
The 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage' is also included, both the `.dll` and `.xml`.

So as far as I see it, everything that is required during runtime has been supplied.

Unfortunately, the exception is telling me that the redirect has not been applied and it is still looking for version `2.1.0.0`. Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 3):

Add a file named after your project so it'll match the name of the assembly.

`{ProjectName}.dll.config` with `Copy to Output Directory = Always` and `Build action = None`

This file has the same syntax as your app.config. It should contains your assembly bindings.

For some reason, the file generated from app.config is not included in the deployment package.

Comment: Cspack does generate this file for you and that is included in the cspkg. Does generating your own manually alter this somehow?

Comment: I don't remember the details but without it, my role was unable to start and on the instance I found out that this .config was missing somewhere. I added it explicitly to my project and noticed that it got properly deployed. Also you role might be deployed at multiple location on the instance, you have to be sure that you are looking at the right (failing) place.

Comment: Unfortunately this did not fix it. Whether you explicitly include the *.dll.config or let cspack generate one for you, the outcome is the same.

Comment: Try to get more details about assembly binding failure with Fuslogvw so you can see if the assembly redirect is detected, where the runtime is looking and check that the .dll.config is present in this folder.

Comment: Any 3 years later, this just saved me when an update to production suddenly went horribly wrong...